# Nvidia Nsight Eclipse edition remote debugging with C/C++ remote launch configuration

Tags: c++, cuda, eclipse-cdt, remote-debugging, nsight

I have a server (Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS - no GUI) with a CUDA-capable GPU installed, and a desktop linux (Fedora 18) machine with no CUDA GPU. I would like to develop my code on my desktop machine and compile then debug it on my remote server machine.

To do this I plan to use Nsight 5 Eclipse edition with the C/C++ Remote launch plugin (as in this example http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_debug_a_remote_application.3F). However, even with all the required plugins (C/C++ Remote Launch, RSE) installed in Nsight, I have no choice of 'C/C++ Remote Application' in the available debug configuration of my project.

Is it a limitation of the Nsight Eclipse IDE or am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: You can connect via SSH x-forwarding (`ssh -X` or `ssh -Y`) from your desktop linux box to your server, then run `nsight` on the server, and remotely debug/profile/develop your application that way.  I'm pretty sure what you're describing here is not supported under nsight EE.

Comment: Note that Nsight EE 5.5 is now available to registered CUDA developers as a part of the CUDA Toolkit 5.5 RC. It supports remote debugging (Toolkit 5.5 should be installed on both ends - client and server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nsight 5.0 does not support remote debugging - as this requires special cuda-gdb server software. cuda-gdbserver and Nsight EE remote debugging will be released as a part CUDA toolkit 5.5 (we demoed CUDA Toolkit 5.5 at GTC last week and we are working hard to release it as soon as possible).

Note that our remote debugger connection UI will be slightly different and will not require any Eclipse plugins installed separately.

**Update:** CUDA Toolkit 5.5 RC (which includes Nsight EE 5.5) is available for download for registered CUDA developers. It includes the remote debug support.